# How can I initialize an empty LinkedHashMap on dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, linkedhashmap

When I try to initialize the LinkedHashMap as `_map = {};` this happens:

> A value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type  `LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>>`.

I tried casting it as: `_map = {} as LinkedHashMap<DateTime  List<Event>>;` but I get:

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List>' in type cast.

I don't have a lot of experience so I'm not sure if I'm doing something kinda dumb.

Comment: Can you include more snippet about the use case, you might want more than initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the [`LinkedHashMap` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap/LinkedHashMap.html) directly:

```dart
_map = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>>();
```

Note that doing so might trigger [the `prefer_collection_literals` lint](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#prefer_collection_literals) (see https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/1649), but in my opinion it's fine to ignore that if you want to be explicit.

Alternatively, if you don't mind being implicit, just rely on the default `Map` implementation already being a `LinkedHashMap`:

```dart
_map = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};
```

Comment: Thanks! this actually answered my question but I actually decided to just use a Map